# Can't load windows 10

Tags: boot

I was using Windows 10 . Yesterday I have tried installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the Installation was successful. I have installed Ubuntu in Seperate Partition. I can boot in to Ubuntu, but there is no option for booting in to Windows.